# ib/main.dart:49:24: Error: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the class 'Set<Map<String, Object>>'

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './question.dart';
import './answer.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyFirstApp());
}

class MyFirstApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return _MyFirstAppState();
  }
}

class _MyFirstAppState extends State<MyFirstApp> {
  var _questionIndex = 0;
  void _ansButtonPress() {
    setState(() {
      _questionIndex = _questionIndex + 1;
    });
  }

  var questions = [
    {
      'questionText': 'What is  your favorate Colour',
      'answers': ['red', 'balck ', 'yellow', 'blue']
    },
    {
      'questionText': 'What is  your favorate Animal',
      "answers": ['Lion', 'Chettah ', 'Leopard', 'Cat']
    },
    {
      'questionText': 'What is  your favorate Movie',
      'answers': ['hai', 'hello ', 'hoe', 'are you']
    }
  ];

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('My first app '),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Question(
              questions[_questionIndex]['questionText'],
            ),
            Answer(_ansButtonPress),
            Answer(_ansButtonPress),
            Answer(_ansButtonPress),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

error in line 49 [image: Screenshot]

**terminal showing like this**

> lib/main.dart:49:24: Error: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the
> class 'Set<Map<String, Object>>'.
> - 'Set' is from 'dart:core'.
> - 'Map' is from 'dart:core'.
> - 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
> Try correcting the operator to an existing operator, or defining a '[]' operator.
> questions[_questionIndex]['questionText'],
> ^
> Failed to package /Users/j3rry01/Documents/Flutter Lab/flutter basics /new_flutter.
> Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
> note: Using new build system
> note: Planning
> note: Build preparation complete
> note: Building targets in parallel
> warning: Capabilities for Signing & Capabilities may not function correctly because its entitlements use a placeholder team ID. To
> resolve this, select a
> development team in the Runner editor. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')

i am a beginner , not so good with the dart concepts , i don't see any error on my POV

Comment: var questions is a List<Map> so if you want a questions it must be with a number or first last etc.. like questions.first or questions[1][_questionIndex]['questionText']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error message it appears that the `questions` variable is been taken as a `Set` and not as a `List`. Try setting its type explicitly like this:

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> questions = [
    {
      'questionText': 'What is  your favorate Colour',
      'answers': ['red', 'balck ', 'yellow', 'blue']
    },
    {
      'questionText': 'What is  your favorate Animal',
      "answers": ['Lion', 'Chettah ', 'Leopard', 'Cat']
    },
    {
      'questionText': 'What is  your favorate Movie',
      'answers': ['hai', 'hello ', 'hoe', 'are you']
    }
];
```

Additionally if you're not going to change the value of the `questions` variable it's better to declare it as `final`

Comment: is this a new update , because the guy guy the tutorial video just used  "var questions = [  " ,after this change now it worked thanks brother